# Database Design: Multiple identifying relationships between two entities

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have two entities `user`, and `message`.

To *avoid* surrogate primary key for `message` it should be a weak entity depending on `user`, having two references of the same (primary key) attribute from `user` - that is `email`, the partial key is supposed to be `unix_timestamp`.

Is it a fine approach? Is there any other good alternative?

Comment: There is nothing fundamentally right or wrong about surrogate keys- I am guessing this is an academic question, but if you are using e.g. user_id, email_id, then timestamp to determine uniqueness you can have the issue (however unlikely) of conflict when two messages are processed at the same time. It depends on how strict you want to be.

Comment: The fundamental wrong thing about surrogate keys is that it drastically reduces the indexing performance on tables with large cardinality, else we could have surrogates surrogates *everywhere*.

Yes you are right, the partial key has to be *clustered* surrogate in this case. I didn't want to jumble up everything that is why didn't talk about that.

Wrong guess by the way.

Comment: You are correct that creating a secondary index for redundant information will slow down write speed but it would not affect lookup, but as I said before, maintaining a timestamp only for uniqueness is fine but can have its pitfalls.

Comment: I tend to find (where I've worked) most tables (multiple projects over 15+ years) have surrogate keys with no major problems. It makes things easier from a consistency/pattern approach. This is mainly using Oracle DB but also SQLServer, Postgres